# If, else if statement not working (only displays if)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, if-statement, syntactic-sugar

It only displays the if statement. Doesn't get to the 2nd or the 3rd statement. The HTML portion only displays out the "commentE" value.

```
var totalAmount = (conversion * sAmount);
totalAmount = $("#totalAmount").val(totalAmount);

var myadvice;
myadvice = $("#myadvice").val();

var great;
great = localStorage.getItem("great");

var commentE;
commentE = localStorage.getItem("commentE");

var between;
between = localStorage.getItem("between");

var betweenb;
betweenb = localStorage.getItem("betweenb");

var commentB;
commentB = localStorage.getItem("commentB");

var less;
less = localStorage.getItem("less");

var commentL;
commentL = localStorage.getItem("commentL");

if (totalAmount >= great) {
    myadvice = $("#myadvice").val(commentE);
} else if ((totalAmount >= between) && (totalAmount <= betweenb)) {
    myadvice = $("#myadvice").val(commentB);
} else if (totalAmount <= less) {
    myadvice = $("#myadvice").val(commentL);
```

These are the HTML portion (index page to get input)

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="between">Between</label>
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <input type="text" 
                        name="between" id="between" placeholder="between" value="200">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <input type="text" 
                        name="betweenb" id="betweenb" placeholder="between" value="499">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="commentB">Comment</label>
            <input type="text" name="commentB" 
                id="commentB" placeholder="comments" value="OK">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

These are supposed to be the results (results page to display the input of previous page

```
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
                <label for="advice"> My Advice is as follows: </label>
                <input type="text" name="advice" id="advice">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</b>
```

Comment: Could you post the html associated with your js ?

Comment: What do you mean? That's what an `else if` is meant to do

Comment: <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                    <div class="ui-field-contain">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
                            <label for="advice"> My Advice is as follows: </label>
                            <input type="text" name="myadvice" id="myadvice">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

Answer (score 1):

If else statements are [executed in order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#Else_if), for example:

```
total = 10;
greater = 5;
between = 4;
if(total >= greater) {
  console.log("comment a");
} else if (total >= between) {
  console.log("comment b");
}
```

The result will be `comment a` because `total >= greater` is tried before `total >= between`. Both statements are true, but the first one is tried first, and only the contents of one statement will be executed. After the code inside an `if else` statement is run the next thing executed is below the `if else` group.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just all kinds of wrong.

```
totalAmount = $("#totalAmount").val(totalAmount);
```

This sets the totalAmount to the jQuery object  `$("#totalAmount")`
You probably wanted to leave it set to a number instead.

```
great = localStorage.getItem("great");
```

This sets great to a string.  Maybe `"5"`.
You probably wanted to call parseFloat to parse this into a number.

```
//so
if (totalAmount >= great) {
//means
if ($("#totalAmount") > "5") {
```

Is a jQuery object greater than a string?  Apparently this is true!  So you get the first if.